# Stop periodic execution of function gracefully

Tags: node.js, typescript

In typescipt/nodejs, how can i gracefully shutdown a component that is repeatedly doing stuff. I.e., i want the user to be able to send `SIGINT` signal e.g. by hitting <ctrl+c> to stop the program **gracefully**:

```
export class Repeater {
  private running: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.running = false;
  }

  public do(): void {
    this.running = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.running) {
        // do stuff
        this.do();
      }
    }, 3000);
  }

  public stop(): void {
    this.running = false;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
const repeater = new Repeater();
process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  repeater.stop();
  process.exit();
});

repeater.start();
```

I've started with the code above, however what is missing is the part where the call to `stop()` is actually blocking until the current execution of `do()` is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a promise from the `stop` method, and exit the process after it resolves. Set it to resolve after the end of the interval when `running` is no longer `true`:

> You referenced a `start` method that you didn't show, so I created one in the code below.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=1#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-AgpFKz2iDgARABlACSAHE4wA5LZR0HHA29Er+9j1Raa5z1WroJBHFwnENh2j1QjAQ5OGGBGE4HMsAP5mCohu4IA)

```ts
export class Repeater {
  private running: boolean = false;
  private finalize: () => void = () => {};
  private done: Promise<void> = new Promise(resolve => this.finalize = resolve);

  public do(): void {
    // do stuff

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.running) this.do();
      else this.finalize();
    }, 3000);
  }

  public start(): void {
    if (!this.running) {
      this.running = true;
      this.done = new Promise(resolve => this.finalize = resolve);
      this.do();
    }
  }

  public stop(): Promise<void> {
    this.running = false;
    return this.done;
  }
}

const repeater = new Repeater();

process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  repeater.stop().then(() => process.exit());
});

repeater.start();
```